# Array: extend \newcolumntype to \provide etc

Tags: tables, arrays

Consider the (silly) MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array, ragged2e}
% in a package
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1\linewidth}<{}}
% here
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1\linewidth}<{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{R{0.3}c}
    Test & test
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Clearly, there will be a warning:

```
Package array Warning: Column R is already defined on input line 6.
```

Now, I understand that the column type **is** redefined (it's not clear to me), but --- is it possible to extend the `\newcolumnstyle` thing in a way similar to `xparse`?

I mean, having the full set of

1. `\newcolumntype`: should error out, say don't change current behavior for compatibility
2. `\providecolumntype` (do not redefine if it exists)
3. `\renewcolumntype` (redefine, no warning if it exists)
4. `\definecolumntype` (redefine always, no warning)

I tried to dig into `array.sty`, but it's too uber-TeX for me... so I am asking to see if anyone has already done it... ;-). Just a way to have the equivalent of `\providenewcolumn` would be great.

Another option is to have a kind of conditional like

```latex
   \ifcolumndefined{R}{then}{else}%
```

or similar...

BTW: I know that I can silence the warning with

```latex
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{array}{Column R}
```

Comment: Do you think that `\providecolumntype` would be useful? If a package that you load defines the column type `Q`, which does something the package author deemed useful, and you say `\providecolumntype{Q}{...}`, you'll find that `Q` does a different thing than you thought. Possibly `\renewcolumntype` might be useful, but doing something like `\renewcolumntype{c}{...}` would not be very funny.

Comment: @egreg you're right, of course, but sometimes the option of choosing between redefining or not (the warning should be there anyway, I think) would be nice.

Comment: `\newcommand\ifcolumndefined[3]{\@ifundefined{NC@find@\string#1}{#3}{#2}}` should work for column types defined with `\newcolumntype`.  The primitive column types can be added like in the definition of `\newcolumntype` in `array.sty`.  Want an answer with that?

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik thanks, that should work. If you want to answer fo for it... but it's not urgent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if a column type exists you can use the same test that `array.sty` does for `\newcolumntype`:

```latex
\newcommand\ifcolumndefined[1]{%
  \edef\NC@char{\string#1}%
  \@ifundefined{NC@find@\NC@char}%
    {\@tempswafalse
     \@tfor\next:=<>clrmbp@!|\do
       {\if\expandafter\noexpand\next\NC@char \@tempswatrue \fi}%
     \if@tempswa \expandafter\@firstoftwo
     \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo
     \fi}%
    {\@firstoftwo}}
```

which will be true if `NC@find@#1` exists, or if `#1` is one of the primitive column types `<>clrmbp@!|`.  This test is not expandable (you probably don't need it to be, but to show off `expl3`), here is an expandable version:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \rmano_if_column_defined:n #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { NC@find@ \token_to_str:N #1 }
      { \prg_return_true: }
      {
        \exp_args:No \rmano_if_primitive_column:NTF { \token_to_str:N #1 }
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \rmano_if_primitive_column:N #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \tl_map_tokens:nn { <>clrmbp@!| }
      { \__rmano_if_primitive_column:NN #1 }
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__rmano_if_primitive_column:NN #1 #2
  {
    \token_if_eq_charcode:NNT #1 #2
      { \tl_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ifcolumndefined \rmano_if_column_defined:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

(`\ifcolumndefined` is a copy of `\rmano_if_column_defined:nTF`, but you can also make copies of the other variants (`:nT`, `:nF`) or copies of `\rmano_if_primitive_column:N(TF)`.)

Here's a full example:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
% \makeatletter
% \newcommand\ifcolumndefined[1]{%
%   \edef\NC@char{\string#1}%
%   \@ifundefined{NC@find@\NC@char}%
%     {\@tempswafalse
%      \@tfor\next:=<>clrmbp@!|\do
%        {\if\expandafter\noexpand\next\NC@char \@tempswatrue \fi}%
%      \if@tempswa \expandafter\@firstoftwo
%      \else \expandafter\@secondoftwo
%      \fi}%
%     {\@firstoftwo}}
% \makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \rmano_if_column_defined:n #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \cs_if_exist:cTF { NC@find@ \token_to_str:N #1 }
      { \prg_return_true: }
      {
        \exp_args:No \rmano_if_primitive_column:NTF { \token_to_str:N #1 }
          { \prg_return_true: }
          { \prg_return_false: }
      }
  }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \rmano_if_primitive_column:N #1 { p, T, F, TF }
  {
    \tl_map_tokens:nn { <>clrmbp@!| }
      { \__rmano_if_primitive_column:NN #1 }
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__rmano_if_primitive_column:NN #1 #2
  {
    \token_if_eq_charcode:NNT #1 #2
      { \tl_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
  }
\cs_set_eq:NN \ifcolumndefined \rmano_if_column_defined:nTF
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\ifcolumndefined{W}{W exists}{W doesn't exist}

\ifcolumndefined{R}{R exists}{R doesn't exist}

\ifcolumndefined{c}{c exists}{c doesn't exist}

\edef\x{\ifcolumndefined{|}{| exists}{| doesn't exist}}
\texttt{\meaning\x}
\end{document}
```